# When are "difference between" questions considered opinion-based, and when not?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, opinion-based

Today I have failed an audit while completing `Close Votes` review.

[The question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32514722/whats-the-difference-between-r-and-r-drawable) has the following formulation:

> `R class` and `R.drawable` class are two different classes within **Android** framework, both of them extends from `Object` class. What is the difference between the two?

[image]

Of course, I can skip this question and keep reviewing. However, I want to understand why I am wrong in order to recognize such questions in future. In my opinion, this question is definitely not an opinion-based question because the original poster asks about the difference between two Java classes which is simple and unambigious.

There are many "difference between" questions at StackOverflow having a good rating:

[Specific difference between bufferedreader and filereader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9648811/specific-difference-between-bufferedreader-and-filereader)
[Difference between float and double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386772/difference-between-float-and-double)
[What is the difference between String and string in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/whats-the-difference-between-string-and-string)
[What is the difference between node.js and io.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27309412/what-is-the-difference-between-node-js-and-io-js)
[What are the differences between struct and class in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92859/what-are-the-differences-between-struct-and-class-in-c)
[Difference between a method and a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155609/difference-between-a-method-and-a-function)
[What's the difference between an argument and a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156767/whats-the-difference-between-an-argument-and-a-parameter)

If you ask "what is the difference between `byte` and `sbyte`", then you will get the plain answer - one is signed, another is unsigned. There will be no place for discussions, arguments, ambiguity or answers like "In my opinion...", "I would...".

So, am I wrong? If yes, then how to determine where is the primarily opinion-based question and where is not?

By the way, the answer to the audit question was definitely not an opinion-based:

> Android.R is a set of built in constants provided by the android SDK. The R class represents the resources in the Android.R xml file.
>
> The R.drawable class contains resources which can be drawn on to the screen. E.g. Bitmaps, NinePatchDrawble etc...

Comment: Why is it primary opinion based?just hard to defend the close vote as such reason for me. If I were a beginner in such situation, I may leave and never contribute to the community again, so don't hesitate to help appealing when see something closed wrongly.

Comment: Valid point, I would properly have flagged as "Too broad" or something like that since finding the differences are not exactly a coding problem. I always struggle with these kind of questions myself.

Comment: Most of your examples are extremely old, and wouldn't survive long, when posted today. If not opinion based, that question is, at very least, too broad. Flagging it as such wouldn't have failed the audit.

Comment: To be honest, even the question should be closed, I still hope to have a precise close reason, an incorrect close reason may mislead not only users, but also visitors that found the post.

Comment: This depends on how much sense the question made in the context of Android programming. "What is the difference between X class and Y class that are wildly unrelated to each other but happen to be in the Android framework" is not on topic - at least not without a deeper explanation of how the question came about. "What is the difference between X class and Y class where both appear to do similar things" is.

Comment: The point of passing an audit is to vote the way everybody else did.  You can interpret posts the way you like and apply your own preferences as to whether a question is opinion-based or not every day of the week.  Doing so at the exact moment you're being audited however is, erm, how can I say this smoothly.  Well, you know.

Comment: It may have an incorrect close reason but changing it is a hassle.  Right now if we wanted to change the close reason we would need to get 5 people to reopen it then 5 people who did not vote to close it in the first place to vote to close for the correct reason.  This is a lot of wasted time and effort on a question that is already closed and would stay closed if we are just changing the close reason.

Comment: "What's the difference" questions make me want to smack a baby.

Comment: @Will: What's the difference between those and any other question, then, in terms of your reaction? :P

Comment: @HansPassant Shouldn't the point of passing an audit be to vote the right way, not the way "everybody else" did? In this case it seems to me that "everybody else" was wrong.

Comment: I have to agree with Anders.  It seems a legitimate question that should not have been closed at all; however, I would add that while the question was definitely answerable in its form a little bit more clarification as to what brought the question on would have helped focus answers a bit.

Comment: If a machine would be smart enough to determine the "right way" there would be excessively few reasons to have humans perform the tedious job of reviewing.  It is not smart enough by a long shot, it can only go by what other humans did.  Something that's pretty easy to find out, both by the machine and you.  It is fine to ignore that lead, but the machine will then assume that you are not paying attention instead of being right.  Because, you know, it's just a machine.  Do this often enough and you'll get blocked.  Good luck then arguing that "everybody is wrong".

Comment: @Pekka웃 Thank you for providing the only comment here with a sane potential explain of what the heck happened on that question. If nothing else, you're right that the OP should explain why they expect there to be any connection in the first place (unless perhaps the connection is immediately obvious to an Android developer).

Answer (score 5):

Note that the vast majority of "what's the difference" questions are Too Broad.  Trying to explain everything about how to different things are different, without narrowing the scope in any way is typically going to encompass a huge amount of information.  Making such a question in scope typically involves something like, "what's the difference between A and B with respect to context X?"

It's also worth noting that its very common for someone to ask an opinion based question, such as, "Should I use X or Y framework?" and then in response to it getting closed, they just edit it into the Too Broad question of, "What's the difference between X and Y Frameworks?"  That progression didn't happen with respect to the one example you gave, but it does come up a lot, so any time you see a question that's pretty clearly *very* broad but closed as being opinion based, it's often because of that (or because people interpreted the, "What's the difference?" as more or less implying the question of, "which should I use?"

Answer (score 3):

The question is considered opinion based when *you* are aware of multiple alternative approaches, but neither of which can be considered "the right one". Usually, questions with "should I use A or B" immediately fall into that category, but "A vs. B" very well could be opinion based too.

To actually decide, you need to know at least something about the area of the question. I.e. "string vs. String in C#" - without basic knowledge about C# you can't say whether this is strictly a language specification question (which it is) or a discussion about some libraries/types with these names that happened to be comparable, and picking one will end up with "tab vs. spaces" discussion.

There is the additional unfortunate case where opinion based/too broad are used as a generic replacement for "no effort whatsoever" as a reason to close, instead of simply downvoting (Which I feel is why the question was closed originally).

On original audit post:

If I'd see one I would skip it because

- Based on languages that I know, there is a good chance that 2 types are absolutely not related (i.e. I'd consider it to be case of `int` vs `Image` in C# - both derive from `Object` but can one really compare such types in a meaningful way?)
- I have no sensible way to find any information (neither "R" nor "drawable"  is really not very well suited for search)
- Overall, it lacks any research - so there is a good chance that it is not a valid question with a tiny, but plausible option of being an OK question.

Based on the current state of that question, I can't see why the two are related (most likely as I'm missing the context of what "Android resources" actually are).

Comment: Asking the technical differences between A and B can sometimes be "too broad" rather than "opinionated".  Otherwise, I agree.